# Is it elegant to pass reference to unknown-length array instead of pointer?

Tags: c++, reference

Please consider the following proof-of-concept snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

const char* random_string_for_the_sake_of_testing = "123";

template <class T>
const T& read_file()
{
    const T* data;

    data = random_string_for_the_sake_of_testing;

    return *data;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << &read_file<char>() << std::endl;
}
```

The ideas is that the `read_file()` function is supposed to return a pointer to a buffer containing the mmap-ed file casted to the requested type. The code will never return `NULL` and the buffer will not be freed as long as the parent object is in the scope, therefore I find returning objects as references more elegant.

However, I'm wondering if it's elegant to actually return references to variable-length arrays like this. That is, convert the pointer to a reference to the first object, and then convert the reference back to a pointer.

Comment: Does this compile? Does it make sense? I think we should be told!

Comment: It compiles and prints `123` http://ideone.com/dwGbkG

Comment: .. But why use a template? Will using any other type work?

Comment: No, it doesn't make any sense. I it is even worse than returning a pointer to an array.

Comment: References are usually used to allow access to a single object, not to an array, so using them only to make sure that it is not a NULL pointer is a bad idea.

Comment: This seems like an extremely ugly hack.

Comment: @H2CO3 - A truly ugly hack is my XXXX at 5am

Comment: @EdHeal XXXX = 4 letters? That should be "face". (no offense)

Comment: Well, my bad for simplifying the code too much. It's actually a class method, with buffer held within the class.

Comment: Casting to a new type `T` makes no sense. Even if `T` is the same as the underlying array (`char` here) the returned reference is not a reference to the array, rather to its first element. If the pointer was ever `NULL` one couldn't dereference it anyway. So what's all this about?

Comment: @H2CO3- no offense taken.

Answer (score 2):

What you shouldn't use:

- a `const char*` - Sure, everybody will recognise that this is *probably* a C-style string and it *probably* won't ever be null, but they'll have to check your documentation to be sure. It may well really just be a pointer to a single `char` that may be null.
- a `const char&` - Definitely don't do this. This actually *implies* that you're only returning a reference to a single `char`. Nobody in their right mind would think "Oh, it's probably a reference to the first character in a C-style string so I need to take the address of it." This is not only going to make people have to read your documentation, but it's also going to confuse them.

What you should use:

- a `std::string` - This is completely unambiguous. You are returning a string, without any doubt, and it can't be null. This describes exactly what your function intends to return.

Answer (score 0):

> The ideas is that the read_file() function is supposed to return a pointer...

If the function is supossed to return a pointer, then return a pointer. If it is not allowed to return `NULL` you can say so in a comment.

Converting the pointer into a reference expecting the user of your function to convert it back to a pointer is not more elegant: it is convoluted.

Keep it simple and the users of your class (maybe yourself?) will appreciate it.